# Java Code for finding grade from marks is incorrect

Tags: java, loops, oop, operators

**Problem: Still getting grade B if marksObtained is below 35**

Have an array stored in database which describes the grading system

**Cannot use switch-case** because different class will have different grading system

```
String[] gradeDetails = {A,60,100,
                         B,45,59.99,
                         C,35,44.99,
                         D,0,34.99};
```

The Logic for deducing grade is

```
int j=0;
while (j<gradeDetails.length/3){
    grade = gradeDetails[j++];
    min = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    max = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    if(marksObtained >= min && marksObtained <= max)
        break;
}
```

- ***SOLVED***

Just used a different variable for different increments

```
j=0;
k=0;
while (k<gradeDetails.length/3){
    grade = gradeDetails[j++];
    min = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    max = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    if(marksObtained >= min && marksObtained <= max)
        break;
    k++;
}
```

Didn't expect the solution to be this silly. **Thanks All**

Comment: `while (j<gradeDetails.length/3){` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your while expression.
`j` is increased by 3 each loop (since you do `j++` three times).
so after the second loop, it equals to 5, which is higher than the length divided by 3 (4), so you're out of the loop.

You should simply use `while j < (gradeDetails.length)`

Answer (score 2):

`gradeDetails.length = 12` => `gradeDetails.length/3` will be 4

```
while (j<gradeDetails.length/3){
    grade = gradeDetails[j++];    // A -> j=0 , B -> j = 4 loop will end
    min = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    max = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    if(marksObtained >= min && marksObtained <= max)
        break;
}
```

So B is simply the last iteration to not brake the loop condition.
You can try this:

```
while (j<gradeDetails.length){
    grade = gradeDetails[j++];    
    min = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    max = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j++]);
    if(marksObtained >= min && marksObtained <= max)
        break;
}
```

OR

```
while (j<gradeDetails.length/3){
    grade = gradeDetails[j*3];
    min = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j*3+1]);
    max = Float.parseFloat(gradeDetails[j*3+2]);
    j++;
    if(marksObtained >= min && marksObtained <= max)
        break;
}
```

OR you can use a 2D-Array

OR you can use a class that wraps mark, min and max.

Comment: understood... i'm gonna try changing some things

Answer (score 0):

The code to achieve what you wanted...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] gradeDetails = { "A", "60", "100", "B", "45", "59.99", "C", "35", "44.99", "D", "0", "34.99" };
        double marks = 0;
        String grade = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < gradeDetails.length; j++) {
            grade = gradeDetails[j];
            j = j + 1;
            double min = Double.valueOf(gradeDetails[j]);
            j = j + 1;
            double max = Double.valueOf(gradeDetails[j]);
            if (marks >= min && marks <= max)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Your grade is :: "+grade);
}
```